# Fish shell testing for existence of file in $PATH

Tags: shell, fish

I'm trying to test in a fish shell script for the existence of the `figlet` binary. Since I use Linux and OS X I cannot rely on the file being in the same location and need to resolve it dynamically. I'm used to doing this with `$(which)` in bash, which works.

With fish though this does not work properly. Why?

```
function print_hostname --description 'print hostname'
  if test -x (which figlet)
    hostname | figlet
  end
end
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `type` in `fish` like in Bourne-like shell:

```
if type -q figlet
  hostname | figlet
end
```

Or to limit to executables in `$PATH` (ignoring functions, builtins):

```
if command -s figlet > /dev/null
  hostname | figlet
end
```

See also [Why not use “which”? What to use then?](/q/85249)